# Update table based on sub select of two other tables

Tags: mysql

I'm really new here and I really need help. I am trying to update a table based on data joined from another select statement.

```
SELECT DISTINCT A.business_unit_AP
                , A.VOUCHER_ID
                , A.JOURNAl_ID
                , A.UNPOST_SEQ
                , A.APPL_JRNL_ID
                , A.PYMNT_CNT
                , A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
                , A.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM,A.dst_acct_type
                , A.LEDGER
                , A.PROCESS_INSTANCE 
FROM PS_PROJ_RES_TMP A 
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_proj_res_cal_vw B
     ON a.business_unit_ap = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_AP
     AND B.PROJECT_ID = A.PROJECT_ID
     AND A.ACTIVITY_ID = B.ACTIVITY_ID 
     AND A.RESOURCE_ID = B.RESOURCE_ID
WHERE A.SYSTEM_SOURCE ='BAP'
     AND b.business_unit_ap is null*
```

So basically the statement above select data from PS_PROJ_RES_TMP table that doesn't exist in PS_PROJ_RES_CAL_VW. Am i right? Then based on the data pulled, I will then update PS_VCHR_ACCTG_LINE.

I formulated this script but its taking too long. And i ended up updating the whole table.

```
UPDATE PS_VCHR_ACCTG_LINE C 
SET C.PC_DISTRIB_STATUS = 'N' 
WHERE EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT DISTINCT A.business_unit_AP
               , A.VOUCHER_ID
               , A.JOURNAl_ID
               , A.UNPOST_SEQ
               , A.APPL_JRNL_ID
               , A.PYMNT_CNT
               , A.VOUCHER_LINE_NUM
               , A.DISTRIB_LINE_NUM
               , A.dst_acct_type
               , A.LEDGER
               , A.PROCESS_INSTANCE 
          FROM PS_PROJ_RES_TMP A 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_proj_res_cal_vw B
              ON a.business_unit_ap = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_AP
              AND B.PROJECT_ID = A.PROJECT_ID
              AND A.ACTIVITY_ID = B.ACTIVITY_ID 
              AND A.RESOURCE_ID = B.RESOURCE_ID
          WHERE b.business_unit_ap is null
          AND b.PROJECT_ID  is null
          AND b.ACTIVITY_ID is null
          AND b.RESOURCE_ID is null
          AND C.BUSINESS_UNIT = a.business_unit_ap
          AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
          AND C.unpost_seq = A.unpost_seq
          AND c.appl_jrnl_id = A.appl_jrnl_id
          AND c.PYMNT_CNT = A.pymnt_cnt
          AND C.voucher_line_num = A.voucher_line_num
          AND C.distrib_line_num = A.distrib_line_num
          AND C.dst_acct_type = A.dst_acct_type
          AND C.ledger = A.ledger
          AND A.SYSTEM_SOURCE ='BAP'
   );
```

Where did i go wrong? Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: Show table schema for `PS_VCHR_ACCTG_LINE`

Answer (score 0):

It is pretty much impossible for an outsider to figure out the issues with your query.  The problem of updating all the rows would seem to be because the logic in the query, on the data in the table, causes a match for all rows.

There is one easy thing you can do to improve performance.  The `distinct` is not necessary when using exists.  So the following should be equivalent:

```
UPDATE PS_VCHR_ACCTG_LINE C 
SET C.PC_DISTRIB_STATUS = 'N' 
WHERE EXISTS 
      (
         SELECT 1
          FROM PS_PROJ_RES_TMP A 
          LEFT OUTER JOIN ps_proj_res_cal_vw B
              ON a.business_unit_ap = B.BUSINESS_UNIT_AP
              AND B.PROJECT_ID = A.PROJECT_ID
              AND A.ACTIVITY_ID = B.ACTIVITY_ID 
              AND A.RESOURCE_ID = B.RESOURCE_ID
          WHERE b.business_unit_ap is null
          AND b.PROJECT_ID  is null
          AND b.ACTIVITY_ID is null
          AND b.RESOURCE_ID is null
          AND C.BUSINESS_UNIT = a.business_unit_ap
          AND C.VOUCHER_ID = A.VOUCHER_ID
          AND C.unpost_seq = A.unpost_seq
          AND c.appl_jrnl_id = A.appl_jrnl_id
          AND c.PYMNT_CNT = A.pymnt_cnt
          AND C.voucher_line_num = A.voucher_line_num
          AND C.distrib_line_num = A.distrib_line_num
          AND C.dst_acct_type = A.dst_acct_type
          AND C.ledger = A.ledger
          AND A.SYSTEM_SOURCE ='BAP';
```

If your original query runs quickly, then I would suggest putting the results in a temporary table and using that for the update.

I would speculate that the performance problem is actually due to `ps_proj_res_cal_vw`, which I further speculate is a view of some sort.  MySQL doesn't always do a good job with optimizing views.